# Python Packing Optimization by Grouping

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I have a real world problem that I believe requires some sort of optimization greater than simple sorts on the arrays of data I am concerned with. I will outline the problem below:

I have a data set comprised of different devices, each having a property A and B. A and B are not dependent on each other, however, I would like to pack 3 of these devices in a particular way.

A values should be similar with respect to each other among the 3 devices selected.

B values should also be similar with respect to each other.

For instance, in this data, there are:

- 250 devices (having a single value of each A and B)
- 90 unique values of A
- 36 unique values of B

Ultimately, these devices should be packed in threes, having a good balance among A values, respectively and B values, respectively. For each property, neighboring bins could also be used if there is not a triplet containing identical values for each criteria.

I would like to group these devices into packages of 3 for as many packages are possible given the constraints.

So my questions are: What sort of combinatorial problem is this and what ways are there to implement it in Python? Any resources regarding these types of problems would be very appreciated as I am rather new to this fascinating subject.

If any part of the explanation is unclear, please let me know and I will try to clarify. Thank you!

**Editing for clarity:**
Here is some example data:

```
DeviceNumber = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
A = [0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
B = [0.02, 0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03]
```

I would want it to group it so that

module 1 would have devices 1,4,5

module 2 would have devices 2,3,6

Let us assume the data for A and B are normally distributed.

I guess I am trying to minimize the variance between just A values and just B values and finding ways to group them by threes.

**Edit 2:**
So, the data is at work and I'm not at the moment, but here are some graphs I made of the value distributions of A and B for 12 devices

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHkhn.jpg

Several devices have the same A value. These devices may also have similar B values among them. If so, I would like to put three of those together, remove them, and repeat checking values and grouping. As matches decrease, I would like to broaden my search criteria for grouping.

I hope that clears up some more of the questions. Thanks again for all the feedback so far!

Comment: how to you define similar among 3 unique values?

Comment: What does similar mean with respect to the unique values? How uniform is the distribution of the unique values of A & B over the total of 250? Are all values of A & B valid? Is size an issue?

Comment: The distribution is fairly normal and all values are valid. The values are intrinsic properties of each device. What size are you referring to? I have tried to further clarify with the edit to my original post.

Comment: I meant all combinations of a&b and the physical size of the items for packing.

Comment: Maybe packing is not the best terminology for me to have used  i mean that the values a and b are my constraints and I must pick 3 devices (that have these two, independent values) to pack into a bin. So there is no size, per se, but a relative agreement between the a values with a secondary objective of b value agreement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be a standard cluster analysis, specifically [k-medoids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids). Given the way k-medoids works, you don't need to remove the clusters from the set, you just have to set *k* to *n* / 3.

There doesn't seem to be an "authoritative" k-medoids Python package implementing the algorithm but [pyCluster](http://bonsai.hgc.jp/~mdehoon/software/cluster/software.htm#pycluster) looks reasonable (with only C-based documentation). It is notably absent from [SciPy.cluster](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.html).

Given the sample data you've presented in the images, you'll wind up with something like this by-eye k-medoids clustering:

[image: k-medoids]

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but the clarification I need won't fit in a comment.

First, if you could make the problem less abstract by saying more about what you are trying to accomplish it would help greatly.

> I would want it to group it so that module 1 would have devices 1,4,5

What does {1, 4, 5} signify? is it (0.3, 0.2, 0.3) by drawing from A? I don't think so. Nor does (0.02, 0.02, 0.02) drawing from B. Neither does the union of those two sets make sense.

> For each property, neighboring bins could also be used if there is not a triplet containing identical values for each criteria.

How do I select "identical values"?

It looks like there could be an interesting question hiding in there, but it is really hard to understand the task specification.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to add some more information as an edit. I hope that clears things up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If the criteria were actually like the sample data you could make a list of tuples containing

```
    [(a[ii]+b[ii], ii)...]
```

then sort the list and pull 3 at a time from each end till you meet at the middle. This would get the combinations most like each other.